# Communicating with Outlook 2013 add-in (Skype for Business)

Tags: vba, outlook, skype-for-business

I have a task involving Outlook 2013 and the Skype for Business add-in (formerly known as Lync).

The add-in has a button which changes an appointment into a "Skype meeting".
[Pic of button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdHbb.png)

Upon clicking this button, the following is added to the email body.[Pic of default text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIjRI.png)

My goal is to change this default text (it isn't editable anywhere else). The way I planned to do this is by creating a macro to call the same function which the "Skype Meeting" button does, and then edit the body of the message after the default meeting text has been placed.

I checked for the "name" of the button via the 'Customize the ribbon' window, and within the 'Skype Meeting' group the 3 buttons had the same description (Macro: OnUCAppointmentOnAction)

Using VBA's object explorer I found the details of the method OnUCAppointmentOnAction:

```
Sub OnUCAppointmentOnAction(asIRibbonControlPtr As Object)
    Member of UCAddinLib.UCAddinCallbackInterface
    method OnUCAppointmentOnAction
```

I have added the library reference within VBA to UCaddin.dll (it's called Office Communicator W14 Type Library), yet when I try to call the macro OnUCAppointmentOnAction I get the error "Sub or Function not defined"

Where am I going wrong? Is there is a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that. That method is implemented by the COM object implementing the IDTExtensibility2 interface that Outlook creates on startup when it loads the addin. In theory, you can do the same, but nobody known what will happen if there are two instances of the addin object instantiated. Simulate a click on the button, then edit the appointment body.

Comment: Many thanks for your response Dmitry! I did look into invoking a click on the button but I could not find out the ID of the button. I did try to use your tool OutlookSpy but I was stuck in locating the "Skype Meeting" button